# warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional. When using two values of the same type

Tags: c

The code should decide which function to use (strcmp or numcmp) based off the value of numeric. It will always result in strcmp but that is irrelevant as the error occurs regardless of the value of `numeric`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int numcmp(char *, char *);

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int numeric = 0;
     int *fun;
     fun = numeric ? numcmp : strcmp;

     return 0;
 }   


 int numcmp(char *s1, char *s2) {
     double v1, v2;

     v1 = atof(s1);
     v2 = atof(s2);
     if (v1 < v2)
         return -1;
     else if (v1 > v2)
         return 1; 
     else
         return 0;
 }
```

When compiling with `gcc --std=c89 test.c` it results in the error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:28: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
    9 |     fun = numeric ? numcmp : strcmp;
      |
```

I can fix this by casting numcmp and strcmp to `(int*)`, but this should be irrelevant as numcmp and strcmp are already of type `int`.

Comment: `int *fun;` That should rather be `int (*fun)(const char*, const char*)` because you set it to point to a function, not an integer.

Comment: "numcmp and strcmp are already of type `int`" - what makes you think that?

Comment: I defined numcmp to be an int and the man page for strcmp says it returns an int

Comment: "I can fix this by casting numcmp and strcmp to (int*), "  - then how are you going to call the function?

Comment: @AviouslyAK `the man page for strcmp says it returns an int` A function is not the same thing as its return type. Lookup function pointers, for a start [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).

Comment: @dxiv ```fun = numeric ? numcmp : strcmp``` assigns fun to the address of either numcmp or strcmp, to be called later. Why does that cause a pointer mismatch though?

Comment: @AviouslyAK Because your `fun` is declared to be the wrong (and incompatible) type, see my first comment. Once you fix that, you'll then need to recheck `numcmp` and make sure it has the same prototype as `strcmp`.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you! Adding const to the parameters of numcmp fixed the issue (and then fixing the declaration of fun fixed the new issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main()` function, in this line `fun = numeric ? numcmp : strcmp;` you think you are assigning the address of either `strcmp` or `numcmp` according to the condition. But that's not how its done in C. Grab your attention on the **code** given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double mul(int a, int b)
{
    return (double)(a*b);
}

int main()
{
    double (*p)(int, int);
    p = mul;
    int a = 10, b = 10;
    printf("%Lf", (*p)(10, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

If you notice, how the pointer `p` is declared and how the address of `mul` assigned to it. That's how we assign the address of a function to a `function` pointer. So, as **dxiv** suggested you in his comment and according to your **code**, 
`numeric ? numcmp : strcmp;` will always return `strcmp` and if you know about the `syntax of strcmp`, its

`int strcmp(const char*, const char*);`

so you should declare `fun` as

`int (* fun)(const char*, const char*);`

and then assign

`fun = numeric ? numcmp : strcmp;`

to it.
Also change the arguments of `numcmp` from `char *` to `const char*`.

Hope, this answer explains why you are getting an incompatibility error.